# Bioshock remastered save date is always Sept 1 2014

Tags: xbox-one, bioshock

I just got the bioshock remastered and am really confused when trying to load games. I have saved a few times and the date time is always on the same day (September 1,2014) and the time makes no sense either.

Has anyone run into this and have a fix for it?[image]

Comment: I had this with my Xbox 360, it reset the system clock every time I switched it on. I can't remember how I fixed it (or whether I even fixed it at all, tbh).

Comment: No worries... glad it's not just me . I was starting to feel like I was going nuts!

Comment: I've opened a ticket with 2K and whatever they tell me is the fix, I'll post it here to save others the pain in the future